# Is there a word that differentiate between image rotation and image translation?

Tags: vision

For an image with an object (e.g., a cat) and its slightly tranlsated image (or its flipped image), an average person can instantly recognize that the objects in the both images are the same (i.e., a cat).

However, for an image with an object and its 90 or 180 degree rotated one, one cannot instantly recognize the objects in the images are the same especially when the object is quite a complacted or unfamiliar one.

In this context, is there a technical terminology (in neuroscience) that differentiate between image rotation and image translation?

Comment: Why not rotation and translation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you are talking about recognition part that say if the image is transformed to be flipped one is able to righaway recognize the object, however if the transformation is say 90 degrees then its hard. I believe the word is [transformation-invariance](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwi-yYbby5HuAhVYVH0KHeSMA0EQFjAEegQIARAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Fyann.lecun.com%2Fexdb%2Fpublis%2Fpdf%2Fsimard-98.pdf&usg=AOvVaw35Q_Udem6geg0dIcwrtBzB).